# HTML5 Cache usage with Querystring

Tags: .net, html, web-services, jsonp, html5-appcache

i have a problem with the HTML5 caching. Here is a brief explanation about the thing i'm trying to do:

- I have a webpage(.aspx) to create and store a form.
- I'm using 2 different webservices in my form. Let's say services are A and B.
- A is a .net webservice and added as a service reference in the
  project.
- B is a simple webpage that returns JSONP data.

I'm calling A via Ajax handler file and calling B with a simple ajax GET method. 
In the CACHE Manifest File, I added my Ajax.ashx file like :
NETWORK:
Ajax.ashx 
and this service works fine. But when i try to call the B(returns JSONP) like :

http://somedomainname.com/writerInfo/?writerID=3

it doesn't work properly. If I add this link to my manifest file like:
NETWORK:
Ajax.ashx
http://somedomainname.com/writerInfo/?writerID=3

 everything works fine.But this must be flexible for different parameters and different values. So how can I handle this kind of situation. How can I force the page to connect network for different querystring parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do:

```
NETWORK:
Ajax.ashx
http://somedomainname.com/writerInfo/
```

You could also do

```
NETWORK:
*
```

to force anything that's not cached explicitly (i.e., listed in the `CACHE` section) to use the network.